# Dynamic Library cannot find the factory defined in main

Tags: c++

I am attempting to implement the code for filling a factory in a dynamically loaded library. The code example here comes from [here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3687?page=0,1).

## Shape.h (The Base Class)

```
#ifndef __SHAPE_H
#define __SHAPE_H

#include <map>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

// base class for all shapes
class shape
{
    public:
    virtual void draw()=0;
};

// typedef to make it easier to set up our factory
typedef shape *maker_t();
// our global factory
extern map<string, maker_t *,less<string> > factory;
#endif // __SHAPE_H
```

## Circle.h

```
#ifndef __CIRCLE_H
#define __CIRCLE_H

#include "Shape.h"

class circle : public shape
{
   public:
       void draw();
};
#endif // __CIRCLE_H
```

## Circle.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Circle.h"

using namespace std;

void circle::draw()
{
    // simple ascii circle<\n>
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "      ****\n";
    cout << "    *      *\n";
    cout << "   *        *\n";
    cout << "   *        *\n";
    cout << "   *        *\n";
    cout << "    *      *\n";
    cout << "      ****\n";
    cout << "\n";
}

extern "C" {
shape *maker()
{
    return new circle;
}

class proxy
{
    public:
        proxy()
        {
            // register the maker with the factory
            factory["circle"] = maker;
        }
};

// our one instance of the proxy
proxy p;
```

}

## Main

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "Shape.h"

using namespace std;

// size of buffer for reading in directory entries
static unsigned int BUF_SIZE = 1024;

// our global factory for making shapes
map<string, maker_t *, less<string> > factory;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *dl;   // handle to read directory
    char *command_str = "ls *.so";  // command string to get dynamic lib names
    char in_buf[BUF_SIZE]; // input buffer for lib names
    list<void *> dl_list; // list to hold handles for dynamic libs
    list<void *>::iterator itr;
    vector<string> shape_names;  // vector of shape types used to build menu
    list<shape *> shape_list;  // list of shape objects we create
    list<shape *>::iterator sitr;
    map<string, maker_t *, less<string> >::iterator fitr;

    // get the names of all the dynamic libs (.so files) in the current dir
    dl = popen(command_str, "r");
    if (!dl)
    {
        perror("popen");
        return(-1);
    }

    void *dlib;
    char name[1024];

    while (fgets(in_buf, BUF_SIZE, dl))
    {
        // trim off the whitespace
        char *ws = strpbrk(in_buf, " \t\n");
        if(ws) 
        {
            *ws = '\0';
        }

        // append ./ to the front of the lib name
        sprintf(name, "./%s", in_buf);
        dlib = dlopen(name, RTLD_NOW);
        if(dlib == NULL)
        {
            cerr << dlerror() << endl;
            return(-1);
        }

        // add the handle to our list
        dl_list.insert(dl_list.end(), dlib);
    }

    int i = 0;
    // create an array of the shape names
    for (fitr=factory.begin(); fitr!=factory.end(); fitr++)
    {
        shape_names.insert(shape_names.end(), fitr->first);
        i++;
    }
    int choice;
    // create a menu of possible shapes to create and let the user make some
    while (1)
    {
        i = 1;
        for(fitr=factory.begin(); fitr!=factory.end(); fitr++)
        {
            cout << i << " - Create " << fitr->first << endl;
            i++;
        }
        cout << i << " - Draw created shapes\n";
        i++;
        cout << i << " - Exit\n";
        cout << "> ";
        cin >> choice;

        if (choice == i)
        {
            // destroy any shapes we created

            for(sitr=shape_list.begin(); sitr!=shape_list.end(); sitr++)
            {
                delete *sitr;
            }

            // close all the dynamic libs we opened
            for (itr=dl_list.begin(); itr!=dl_list.end(); itr++)
            {
                dlclose(*itr);
            }

            return(1);
        }

        if (choice == i - 1)
        {                
            // draw the shapes
            for (sitr=shape_list.begin(); sitr!=shape_list.end(); sitr++)
            {
                (*sitr)->draw();
            }
        }

        if (choice > 0 && choice < i - 1)
        {
            // add the appropriate shape to the shape list
            shape_list.insert(shape_list.end(), factory[shape_names[choice-1]]());
        }
    }
}
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

> ./libCircle.so: undefined symbol: factory

How can I get *libCircle.so* to see the factory map and update it?

Comment: 1) you can pass factory as parameter; 2) you can export it from executable and link your dynamic library to executable.

Comment: It needs to be dynamically loaded.

Comment: Both approaches allow it to be loaded dynamically.

Comment: I need the feature of automatic registration by using the Proxy method.  I would like to use this in my code for my job assignment.  So how can the factory be used w/o passing it as a parameter and w/o linking it to the executable?

Comment: Try to declare `factory` with `extern "C"` in `Shape.h`

Comment: `factory` with `extern "C"'` is already in `Shape.h`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that symbols in the executable are not exported by default, and so are not available for libraries loaded by `dlopen` to resolve against.

From the manual for [GNU ld](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html#index-dynamic-symbol-table):

```
   -E
   --export-dynamic
   --no-export-dynamic
       When creating a dynamically linked executable, using the -E option or
       the --export-dynamic option causes the linker to add all symbols to the
       dynamic symbol table.  The dynamic symbol table is the set of symbols
       which are visible from dynamic objects at run time.

       If you do not use either of these options (or use the
       --no-export-dynamic option to restore the default behavior), the
       dynamic symbol table will normally contain only those symbols which are
       referenced by some dynamic object mentioned in the link.

       If you use "dlopen" to load a dynamic object which needs to refer back
       to the symbols defined by the program, rather than some other dynamic
       object, then you will probably need to use this option when linking the
       program itself.

       You can also use the dynamic list to control what symbols should be
       added to the dynamic symbol table if the output format supports it.
       See the description of --dynamic-list.

       Note that this option is specific to ELF targeted ports.  PE targets
       support a similar function to export all symbols from a DLL or EXE; see
       the description of --export-all-symbols below.
```

So your solutions are:

- link against a stub shared object which uses the symbols that should be exported (see the "*referenced by some dynamic object mentioned in the link*" text in the man page)
- move the shared symbols into a separate shared object which the executable and the `dlopen`'d libraries can all (dynamically) link
- explicitly export `factory` from the executable at link time with `--dynamic-list`
- explicitly export *all* symbols from the executable at link time with `--export-dynamic`

Comment: I modified my makefile and everything works now.  Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining a "C++" symbol `factory` in main.cpp, however, you are referencing a "C" symbol "factory" in the other files. You have to make `factory` an extern "C" in main.cpp aswell.

Comment: I don't see `extern "C"` there, just `extern`. Did I miss an edit?

Comment: Sorry, I miss spoke.  I meant to say that I already tried that. Thanks.